# Controller subdirectories?

Tags: symfony

I would like to isolate some controllers in a subdirectory in my Symfony2 app.
Something like that:

```
route:
  resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/Admin/"
  type:     annotation
  prefix:   /admin/
```

In this directory there is 6 controller class.
I can import these separatly but it's not practical ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remove the trailing slash: resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/Admin"

Answer (score 10):

I use this which includes every controller in that folder:

```
core:
  resource: "@AppCoreBundle/Controller"
  type: annotation
```

The same code applies to subfolders:

```
core_admin:
  resource: "@AppCoreBundle/Controller/Admin"
  type: annotation
```

It's perfectly okay to create subfolders inside the Controller folder to split your public and admin controllers.

Of course you could include each of them one by one instead, but that's extremely tedious.

Comment: where is this file to add the new controller folder?
_(edit) i got it! the routing file... routing.yml_

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do anything special, the code below **includes** subdirectories like

```
/Controller/admin/
```

for example.

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Answer (score -6):

Its not good practice to do like that.
Why can you make the extra bundle if you really like to isolate the stuff.

Then you can make them as service and access from where ever you want

See here http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/controller/service.html

Comment: Is a symfony best practice: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#routing-configuration