# How to import resources from a given controller directory structure in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, directory-structure

I'm working on an application that is growing rapidly which is causing more and more controllers over time and I'm always trying to maintain good practices for do not have as many lines per controller. Right now are almost 40 controllers in `Controller` directory and it's a bit complicated found one when need to add code or edit or something else so I'm thinking in order them inside subfolders under `Controller` directory as follow:

```
src\
    AppBundle\
        Controller\
            Comunes\
                CiudadController.php
                DuplicadosCedulaController.php
                ...
            RegistroUsuarios\
                EmpresaController.php
                NaturalController.php
                ...
            RPNI\
                CodigoArancelarioController.php
                RPNIProductoPaso1Controller.php
                ...
            BuscarEmpresaController.php
            DistribuidorController.php
            ...
```

But that reorder is causing this error on my application:

> FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource
>   "/var/www/html/project.dev/src/AppBundle/Controller/" from
>   "/var/www/html/projectdev/app/config/routing.yml". (Class
>   AppBundle\Controller\EmpresaController does not exist)

Since apparently Symfony is not able to find the controller class when it's not on `Controller` directory. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22826188/719427) topic but is not clear to me what the problem is. I don't know if this is possible or not I read [Controller Naming Pattern](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#controller-naming-pattern) at Symfony docs but is not so helpful. Any advice around this? A workaround? Suggestions for a better project structure organization?

Note: I made only one bundle because has no sense more than one since the application will not works for separate bundles so following [Syfmony Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html) I come with only one bundle

**Edit**

This is weird and I don't know how all is working again, I've move all the controllers from `Controller` to subfolders inside that directory as my example above shows and didn't change nothing at all on `routing.yml` and Symfony keep getting controllers even if they are in subfolders: amazing!! Ahhh very important just remember **CLEAR CACHE** command, the most important Symfony command I believe, many of developers issues are cause of this, I forgot complete to clear it and test changes!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

routing:

```
st_mainsiteweb_admin_subsite_create_template:
    path: /subsite/create-template
    defaults:
        _controller: STMainSiteWebBundle:Admin/SubSite:createTemplate
```

directory structure:

```
ST\
  MainSiteWebBundle\
             Controller\
                      Admin\
                         SubSiteController -> createTemplateAction
```

Is this are you looking for?

Comment: I'm not test your solution and perhaps it works but since my code start working again I'll give points to you, take a look to my edition

Comment: @ReynierPM I've seen this technique in Sylius source code since I'm using it.. But your solution is weird, double check if it's working correctly even it's working now..

Comment: Already checked I'm working on it now, adding things and much more, I test and re-test it but don't worry I'll come back here if any mistake is present

Answer (score 1):

I do it 2h, now is ok, no routing, no other file.

Just change the namespace of

```
CiudadController.php
DuplicadosCedulaController.php
....
```

from AppBundle\Controller to AppBundle\Controller\Comunes

Answer (score 0):

I never tried that so it's just a theoretical answer.  If you want to have the controllers like this is perfectly fine, but then you should need to map them [in the routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498569/controller-subdirectories).

```
Controller\
        Comunes\
            CiudadController.php
            DuplicadosCedulaController.php
```

Then will be matched in routing yaml:

```
comunes:
    resource: "@yourBundle/Controller/Comunes"
    type: annotation
```

And so on for every different directory. As far as I know they are automatically loaded from Controller/ directory, but if you place them on any other place you need to reference them in the routing.