# Symfony 3.2.1 - bundle controllers in sub-directories

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.1

EDIT | I tried prefixing controllers class name with "Web" - no dice :(

According to everything I have read and previously experienced:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html

I should be able to move/organize controllers into sub-folders but now I cannot seem to get Symfony to cooperate:

```
AppBundle/Controller
  - MemberController.php
  - DefaultController.php
```

Works fine - but if I move

```
AppBundle/Controller
  /web/MemberController
  - DefaultController
```

Then clear the cache - I get the following error(s):

```
  [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                                                                       
  Class AppBundle\Controller\MemberController does not exist in /var/www/project/src/AppBundle/Controller (which is being imported from "/var/www/project/app/config/routing.yml").  

  [ReflectionException]                                       
  Class AppBundle\Controller\MemberController does not exist
```

Of course it doesn't I moved it up down one directory into a sub-folder "web". What gives? My routing.yml is as simple as:

```
site:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
```

Comment: Not a big fan of annotations but here are a couple of things to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498569/controller-subdirectories Also wondering if you added web to your MemberController namespace?

Comment: The namespace was the ticket...thx :)